# Mixing Promise with Subscription

Tags: javascript

I have a subscription method named foo. I see the console output for each iteration of next.
I would like to call this method from another file and perform an action for every iteration of next.  If I try to use a .then() it just catches the last instance (as expected).

What is the best way to modify this code to be able to perform an action for every iteration?  I got it working by modifying the code to pass a callback to foo as a parameter. However, is that the best option or is there a better way?

```
// MySubscriptions.js
import {execute} from 'apollo-link';
import {SubscriptionClient} from 'subscriptions-transport-ws';
import {WebSocketLink} from 'apollo-link-ws';

const link = new WebSocketLink(new SubscriptionClient('blah'));

async function foo(someQuery) {
   return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
     execute(link, {query: someQuery })
       .subscribe({
         next: (result) => {
           console.log('Resolving', result);
           resolve(result);
         },
         error: (err) => reject(err);
         complete: () => console.log('done');
       });
  });
}

export default {
  runTestSubscription: () => foo('MyTestLink'),
};

// MyMainFile.js
import MySubscriptions from 'MySubscriptions.js'
MySubscriptions.runTestSubscription().then((result) => { console.log('Then', result); });
```

Comment: Returning a `Promise` from an async function is redundant. Also since you're not using `await` using `async` is kinda pointless. Have you tried using [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of converting the `Observable` to a `Promise`, return the `Observable` directly, and then use `subscribe` instead of `then` in the other file.

```
// MySubscriptions.js
import {execute} from 'apollo-link';
import {SubscriptionClient} from 'subscriptions-transport-ws';
import {WebSocketLink} from 'apollo-link-ws';

const link = new WebSocketLink(new SubscriptionClient('blah'));

function foo(someQuery) {
  const obs = execute(link, { query: someQuery });
  obs.subscribe({
    next: (result) => console.log('Resolving', result),
    complete: () => console.log('done')
  });
  return obs;
}

export default {
  runTestSubscription: () => foo('MyTestLink'),
};

// MyMainFile.js
import MySubscriptions from 'MySubscriptions.js'
MySubscriptions.runTestSubscription().subscribe((result) => { console.log('Then', result); });
```